# Python - locate element in set of tuples

Tags: python, set, tuples

I have a set of tuples, each tuple has a finite number of elements.

I would like to check if there is a certain element in that set,
that has the specific component i am searching for.

```
set_of_tuples = {(el_11, el_12, el_13), (el_21, el_22, el_23)}
a = (dont_care, el_12, dont_care)
```

how can i locate the tuple element in the set, that contains that specific component?

I could do this using a list comprehension, but it is a very slow proccess.

Using sets, with simple cases, i can do something like this:

```
el = (1,2)
set_of_tuples = {(1,2), (2,3) ...}
```

i can verify if it exists, doing:
el in set_of_tuples.

What i asm asking, is is there is a way of doing the exact same thing, but without caring about some tuple element, for example:

```
el = (_,2)
el in set_of_tuples
```

Comment: So you want to check if a certain element (`el_12`) is found in a certain position (second position)?

Comment: correct. @Adirio

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Hi @RafaelMarques, to accomplish maximum optimisation a question arise, are you going to look over the same set of elements (or minimum changes)  multiple times?

If the answer is yes, you could do so one-time slow ordering method to your data and then look over using some optimal algorithm as QuickSort. I could try to help you if this is your scenario.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> if this Element exists in any tuple of that set

With `any()` function:

```
set_of_tuples = {(11, 12, 13), (21, 22, 23)}
el = 12
exists = any(el in t for t in set_of_tuples)

print(exists)    # True
```

---

To get *the position within the outer set*:

```
pos = -1
for i,t in enumerate(set_of_tuples):
    if el in t:
        pos = i
        break

print(pos)
```

Comment: this does indead verify is that element exists.
is it also possible to find the specific location of that element?

Comment: @RafaelMarques, you mean specific location within inner tuple OR the position within the outer set, OR both positions?

Comment: i see your solution, and it is correct, as it gives exactly what i asked for.
however, i am still worried about execution time, this is a very slow process.
I am trying to do this without list comprehension, and using sets, because it is fast.
for example, given a set
li = [i for i in range(0,100000)]
set_li = set(li)
doing:
if 50000 in set_li:
   print('found')
takes so few time, that python rounds the result to 0.0
if i do the same with list comprehension, it takes around 0.06 second.

so what i am asking, is if there is a way(that u know) to do:
(_, element) in set_of_tuples,

Comment: @RafaelMarques, `set` gives you a quick search on **exact** seach values, but not partially like `(<unknown>, 12, <unknown>)`. When set if filled with sequences - you should specify the exact sequence to search

Comment: @RafaelMarques Since sets are unordered, how does the position help?